# How to solve the matricial equation $ A A^T = B$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve the equation $ A A^T = B$ , where $A$ and $B$ are $ 5 \times 5$. I don't know if have an algorithm for this. I trying to do an application for a particular case of the fomula (3.9) of this paper: http://www.markfisher.net/~mefisher/papers/term_prem.pdf

I'm assumig that $\mathscr{F}(t, s)$ constant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know anything about $A$ or $B$ besides their size?

Comment: If $B$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, there are infinitely many solutions; the Cholesky decomposition gives one. If not, there are no solutions.

Comment: Actually I don't know, $B$ may be diagonal, but ins't  guaranteed.

Comment: Typically, when you "solve" an equation, there are knowns and unkoowns.  What is known in this equation?  Are we given the matrix $B$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this problem for the case $B = I$.

Let $M$ be any $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix, so that $MM^t = I$ and construct
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
&   &   & 0 & 0\\
& M &   & 0 & 0\\
&   &   & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $AA^t = I$. In short, there's an infinite family of solutions to this problem. The same kind of idea applies in general (if $B$ is nonnegative definite), and if $B$ is NOT, then there are no solutions.

(For the general case, suppose that $UU^t = B$. Let $V = UA$; then $VV^t = UA A^t U^t = U (AA^t) U^t = UIU^t = UU^t = B$. So if there is a solution, then there's an infinite family of solutions.)

So there's not much help we can give you in finding "the solution", and that suggests to me that perhaps you might be looking for the wrong thing (but I'm not certain about that last part).